# Outlook Add In Recipient Not Being Returned

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm creating an Outlook Add-in that will take the recipients and check to see if they exists in our database.

When the user clicks on a mailto link on a page it will pop up the Outlook compose window and the recipient will be populated
as such.

[image: to-text-mail]

Running the Add-in will lead to a nothing being returned from the Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync function.

```
    Office.initialize = function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync(getRecipientFromDB);
        });
    };
```

However, the recipient will now look like this:

[image: to-text-mail-2]

Retrying the Add-in will now work because the Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync function will actually return a result.

My Outlook version is 16.0.11029.20045.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Comment: Just want to clarify this - getRecipientFromDB is a callback function, and you're validating the result right?

Comment: It would be useful to know your Outlook version. There's a post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537433/office-context-mailbox-item-to-getasync-updates-to-field-with-partial-data which talks about functionality being fixed in 16.0.8309.1000

Comment: @MaviDomates Yup, getRecipientFromDB will validate the result before doing anything. I have also updated the question with my Outlook version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to.getAsync will return every resolved recipient in the "to" field. In the first screenshot, test@test.com is not resolved, so to.getAsync will not return anything. If you open the compose window, wait until recipients resolve, and then run the add-in, to.getAsync will return a result.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the insight. I have indeed seen that it will eventually resolve. Is there anyway to speed up this process?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to speed up resolving recipients. You could use the RecipientsChanged event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype?view=office-js), which triggers when the recipient list changes, to know when recipients have resolved.

Comment: I'll look in that and see if it will work for my purpose. Thank you very much for you time and answering my question! Much appreciated!